Does any recognize this notation which is supposed to be used in former USSR countries?
One of my students recently used a strange notation in a quiz that looks like an equals sign rotated by 45 degrees. He claimed it meant "everything before this is incorrect and should be ignored." He also mentioned he could show me his high school notebook where this notation was used regularly in his home country, a former USSR member country.
Has anyone seen this notation before? Is this a recognised regional mathematical symbol?
The reason I'm asking is that if I interpret this symbol as a minus sign, then the student has answered the problem incorrectly.
However, if the student is telling the truth about its meaning, the part of his answer after this symbol would actually be correct.
In other words
$$\binom{12}{7} - \binom{8}{1} + \binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{8}{6} + \binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{7}{3} + \binom{7}{2}$$
is incorrect but
$$\binom{8}{1} + \binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{8}{6} + \binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{7}{3} + \binom{7}{2}$$
is correct.


It would be good to know what part of what expression should be ignored and how that relates to a minus sign. Personally I think: students should learn to use common notation instead of assuming we know all their  high school notebooks.

Still very unclear. How can we tell if $a-b+c+d$ is  "correct" or $-b+c+d$ is "correct"?

$a-b+c+d$ is wrong. $b+c+d$ is correct.

@KurtG. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the post to clarify.

Then that student should simply have striked out ${12\choose 7}-,.$

Well, he is from one of the former USSR countries and he claimed that this is how they wrote things there.

Then tell him that this is what they formerly wrote. Besides: it is totally unclear what that symbol wants to eliminate. A strike out should be clear even to a cave man.

The confusion about the minus sign is a good example of why this notation is not clear: Is that symbol placed before or after the minus sign.

See this answer.  It asserts that in programming the double-slash notation means "ignore the comment following this mark".  It is conceivable that similar notation is used in proofreading for ignoring material preceding the mark. Therefore the student might be telling the truth.
Why not ask him to show "his high school notebook where this notation was used regularly in his home country" ?

In $C,C++$ and Java // means the compiler should ignore what is after the double slash. The student's notation conflicts with this in at least two ways: he put the double slash below the minus sign and tells us he wants us to ignore what is before it.
